# LCD monitor flicker on one monitor in dual-monitor setup

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, hardware-failure, lcd, refresh-rate

I have a dual monitor setup, one monitor is a new LCD widescreen, the other is a old square LCD monitor, before I got the new one I would always fix the flicker by setting the refresh rate to 75Hz, but now because I have the new monitor connected windows no longer allows me to set the frequency above 60Hz, and the flicker is back and irritating my eyes.

Old monitor: i-inc CY199D (VGA connection)

New monitor: Acer P205H (Digital)

OS: windows 7

PC: nVidia GForce 8800GTS

Is there any way I can set the frequency higher on one but not the other, or maybe somehow fix the flicker on the old one?  Setting hide modes that this monitor cannot display to off, does not show any more refresh-rates, just the 60Hz.

Comment: If you mean that your old monitor is a CRT then you should probably indicate that. "Old square monitor" is not really descriptive enough.

Comment: @Ignacio Both are LCD

Comment: @Ignacio I assume by 'square' Yuri means 'not widescreen' aka 4:3.

Comment: @Shinrai: I've heard enough people refer to CRTs as "big squares" that I prefer not to assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you force the old monitor to auto-resync yet?

I have an old Gateway LCD that occasionally loses it's settings and flickers like crazy at 60hz (where Windows likes to keep setting my video card) but it is fine at 75hz (when I override).

I eventually figured out that I could just auto-resync the monitor on those rare occasions and not have to mess around with changing my refresh rate...

...

Comment: please tell me more about auto-resync?

Comment: There's a button on my monitor that forces it to resynchronize with the display.  Pressing that once the system is up and running solves the flicker.

Comment: http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/clock_phase.php how to fix flicker if you don't have that magic button.